# Удаление коммитов на git и открытие через svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Сделала удаление последних двух коммитов в git, но через svn они все равно остались. Как через svn в idea подгрузить актуальную версию? Спасибо.

Удалила коммиты через git bash. Развернула заново проект с гита через git bash, потом подчистила коммиты.
svn в idea по указанному репозиторию вытаскивает проект.

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), как у вас связаны git и svn.

Comment: "Сделала удаление последних двух коммитов в git" — также уточните, пожалуйста, как именно вы удаляли коммиты?

Comment: вы что-нибудь делали с автоматически созданной веткой `git-svn`?

Answer (score 3):

Главное правило хорошего тона в git - не править опубликованные коммиты.

В svn нет механизма удаления коммитов. Единственный способ - создать новый репозиторий и перенести туда все коммиты кроме ненужных.

Поэтому вам стоило не удалять коммиты, а сделать новый коммит, отменяющий ненужные изменения.

Comment: `создать новый репозиторий и перенести туда все коммиты кроме ненужных` – омг, всё настолько сложно? Может быть, вернуть в git старые коммиты, а на них сверху ещё одним — новые изменения?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, собственно об этом я и написал в третьем абзаце. Сейчас попытаюсь найти как восстановить в git коммиты из svn

Comment: git reflog можно

Comment: @NickVolynkin, зависит от того, что именно произошло с веткой `git-svn`. Если ее удалить, то reflog тоже удаляется. И если эта ветка будет не на последнем коммите, который получен из svn, то все коммиты между последним обновлением и положением ветки просто будут отсутствовать (уже проверил).

Comment: Хм, а мы с вами про один и тот же `git reflog` говорим? В мой попадают все ревизии, на которые указывает `HEAD`, а пропадают они из него только когда проходит достаточно времени. А при различном «удалении» коммитов они там как раз остаются — это позволяет использовать рефлог в качестве бэкапа.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если есть хоть одна ветка, которая в течении последних двух недель ссылалась на нужный коммит, то да, можно восстановить из reflog. Сам он физически хранится в подпапке `.git/logs/`, в файлах, соответствующих именам веток. Если ветку удалить, то и файл лога тоже удаляется. То, что коммит есть не только в истории ветки, но и в `HEAD` - я забыл.

Comment: Приятно поспорить со знающим человеком. ))